# NSDateFormatter returns nil in swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2, nsdate, nsdateformatter

When I converting my string to `NSDate`, it is returning `nil`

And show error :

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

for example :     date = 8/9/2016 9:45:19 AM

```
convertDate(DateString:String) -> NSDate{
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(DateString)
    print(date) // return nil

    return date! 
}
```

You can guide what is the reason?

Comment: The same question has alreldy been asked here over and over.

Comment: Since `found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` is the new `date formatter returns nil`, you managed to elevate the situation to a new level by using these two in a same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `dateFormatter` can not convert the `DateString` you are passing it, given the `dateFormat` you have told it to use.

Therefore it gives up and returns `nil`, meaning that when you've run this line:

```
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(DateString)
```

the value of `date` is `nil`

Next, you take the value of `date` and say "force unwrap this value and return it, I don't care if it is nil or not", as can be seen here.

```
return date!
```

As your function is expected to return a `NSDate`...meaning that you guarantee that you will *always* return an instance of `NSDate` and not `nil`, and you then tell it to force unwrap something that can be (and is in this case) `nil` your app keels over when you try to force unwrap `date`.

In general, force unwrapping things in Swift is almost always a bad idea, unless you are absolutely sure that the value is not `nil`.

So, a couple of things to consider:

1. How does your `DateString` actually look? There must be something wrong with either that or your `dateFormat` string since this value can not be parsed.
2. Should you always return a `NSDate`? Or could you return an optional instead and let the caller of your method worry about whether your `convertDate` method returns something useful or not?

Hope that gives you something to work with.

Comment: I checked these but The problem is that when I'm testing this error occurs on mobile phones.The problem is that when I'm testing this error occurs on mobile phones

Comment: OK, could it be that the date format on those phones are different than the one you are expecting? Different region formats for instance?